# When I receive a page visit, it automatically sends a friend request

Tags: javascript

So I am  trying to make it so when someone views my profile on the website : playcraftmc.com/profile/1252121

It makes the person automatically send me a friend request. Here is what I have so far.

`<script>
Enjin_Profile_Friends.gi().followUser(1252121)
</script>`

Now this works, it makes the user send a friend request if they are logged in, except it keeps refreshing the page. I am very new to js and I don't know if you can make it so it only executes the script once.

By the way, I do have administrator access on this website, and this code is directly embeded in the website.

Comment: unless there's an Enjin_Profile_Friends command to look and see if you've already got a friend request for the user I'd set a cookie when you first send the friend request and if it's set don't send another request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what the source code looks like:

```
> Enjin_Profile_Friends.gi().followUser
function(user_id) {
    $.post('/ajax.php?s=friends', {
        op: 'add',
        user_id: user_id
    }, function(result) {
        if (result.error != undefined && result.error) Enjin_Core.alert(result.error);
        else document.location.reload();
    }, 'json');
}
```

Delete the parts you done need:

```
function(user_id) {
    $.post('/ajax.php?s=friends', {
        op: 'add',
        user_id: user_id
    }, 'json');
}
```

And it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.post('/ajax.php?s=friends', {
        op: 'add',
        user_id: '1252121'
    }, 'json');
</script>
```